# A question associated with inductive probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm confused about the following proof technique used by many research papers in probability. Let $\{X_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables such that $X_0\leq 1$ with probability $1$. Suppose that, for $k\geq 1$, if $X_{k-1}\leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$, then
$$\mathrm{P}\Bigl(X_k\leq \frac{1}{2^k}\big)\geq 1-\epsilon$$  Here, $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ is a constant. Then one can claim that $\mathrm{P}(X_k\leq \frac{1}{2^k})\geq 1 - k\epsilon$ for $k\geq 0$ (without any conditioning). How do we get this conclusion? When $k=0,1$ the statement is trivial. If, for example, $k=2$, my though is to compute this
$$
\mathrm{P}\Bigl(X_2\leq \frac{1}{4}\big)\geq \mathrm{P}\Bigl(X_2\leq \frac{1}{4}\mid X_1\leq \frac{1}{2}\big)\mathrm{P}\Bigl(X_1\leq \frac{1}{2}\big)\geq (1-\epsilon)^2
$$
which leads to the bound $\mathrm{P}\Bigl(X_2\leq \frac{1}{4}\big)\geq 1-2\epsilon$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yor are only one step to go! Hint: using your idea for $X_2$, to show that $\mathbb P(X_k<1/2^k)\ge(1-\epsilon)^k$, and thus $(1-\epsilon)^k\ge 1-k\epsilon$ (which you can prove it by a lot of methods)

Comment: You're correct. Thanks!